# Does every connected component of $\{z : |P(z)|<1 \}$ contain a zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

> Let $P(z)$ be a complex non-constant polynomial. Let $G$ be a connected component of open set $\{z : |p(z)|<1 \}$. How to prove that $G$ contains a zero of $P$?

I have no idea how to even start; maybe I don't know the required theorem? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider $$\min\{|p(z)|: z \in G \} =  \min\{|p(z)|: z \in   \overline{G} \}=|p(z_0)|.$$
If $p(z_0) \neq 0$, then the same arguments as in [the proof of Fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) imply that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $z_1$ s. t. $|z_0-z_1| < \epsilon$ and $|p(z_1)| <|p(z_0)|$. Thus we obtain the contradiction.